# Can't reference a function from a class to another class WP8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I want to reference a function from a class to another class.

I have this first class:

```
using Jumper.Core.Model;
using Jumper.Core.PlatformServices;
using Jumper.Core.PlatformServices.Storage;
using Jumper.Core.Services;
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Jumper.Core.Client
{
public sealed class Client
     <TBaseSaveData,
    TDeviceServiceHelper,
    TGeoLocationService,
    TNetworkService>
    where TBaseSaveData : BaseSaveDataService, new()
    where TDeviceServiceHelper : IDeviceServiceHelper, new()
    where TGeoLocationService : IGeoLocationService, new()
    where TNetworkService : INetworkService, new()
{

    private readonly int appId;
    private readonly string appVersion;
    public readonly ServiceFactory<TBaseSaveData,
        TDeviceServiceHelper,
        TGeoLocationService,
        TNetworkService> serviceFactory;

    #region Constructors

    internal Client
        (int appId, string appVersion)
    {
        this.appId = appId;
        this.appVersion = appVersion;

        this.serviceFactory = new ServiceFactory<TBaseSaveData,
        TDeviceServiceHelper,
        TGeoLocationService,
        TNetworkService>();
    }
    #endregion

public async Task<TrackingItem> CreateDefaultItem()
    {
        Tuple<double, double> location = await this.serviceFactory.GeoLocationService
            .GetUnifiedGeoLocation();

        var assemblyService = this.serviceFactory.AssemblyInfoService;
        var deviceService = this.serviceFactory.DeviceServiceHelper;
        var seconds = (DateTime.UtcNow -        this.serviceFactory.TrackingService.StartTime).TotalSeconds;
        TrackingItem item = new TrackingItem()
        {

            //APP
            AppId = this.appId,
            RunningSeconds = (int)seconds,
            AppVersion = this.appVersion,
            Language = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName,
            Country = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name.Substring(3, 2),

        };
        return item;
    }
```

I want to use the function CreateDefaultItem() in other class but i can't...
This is what i do and doesn't work:

```
using Jumper.Core;
...
...

Jumper.Core.Client.CreateDefaultItem();
```

What i have to do for use the function CreateDefaultItem on another class?

Thanks!

Comment: CreateDefaultItem() is an instance method not a static method, so you cannot call it like that

Comment: so... how can i call it?

Comment: I don't know how to call it... any help?

Comment: var c = new Jumper.Core.Client.Client();  var item = await c.CreateDefaultItem()

Comment: I tried that but this happened: using the generic Jumper.Core.Client.Client()<TBaseSaveData,TDeviceServiceHelper,    TGeoLocationService,NetworkService> requires 4 type arguments

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
public async Task<TrackingItem> CreateDefaultItem()
```

You need this:

```
public static async Task<TrackingItem> CreateDefaultItem()
```

Note the added "static" keyword. This makes a method call independent of any specific instance of the class.

The drawback, however, is that the method body can only use other static members of the class (static fields, static properties, static methods).

Comment: Yes, but if I put static on that i have to modify all the elements with "this." ...

Comment: Actually you will find that the "this" keyword is not valid within a static method. As I said, static methods are *independent of any specific instance of the class.*